# Swift Date formatter strange issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

developers.
I have a problem with Swift date formatter.
I'm using HorizontalCalendar to display a calendar on an iOS app.
That's the code that I used.

```
private lazy var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    private lazy var dayDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.calendar = calendar
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(
            fromTemplate: "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy",
            options: 0,
            locale: calendar.locale ?? Locale.current)
        return dateFormatter
    }()
    
    private func makeContent() -> CalendarViewContent {
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        
        let startDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: Date.currentYear ?? 1, month: Date.currentMonth ?? 1, day: Date.currentDay ?? 1))!
        let endDate = calendar.date(from: DateComponents(year: (Date.currentYear ?? 1) + 1, month: 12, day: 31))!
        
        return CalendarViewContent(
            calendar: calendar,
            visibleDateRange: startDate...endDate,
            monthsLayout: .vertical(options: VerticalMonthsLayoutOptions()))
            
            .withInterMonthSpacing(24)
            .withVerticalDayMargin(8)
            .withHorizontalDayMargin(8)
            
            .withDayItemModelProvider { [weak self] day in
                let textColor: UIColor
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    textColor = .label
                } else {
                    textColor = .black
                }
                
                let dayAccessibilityText: String?
                if let date = self?.calendar.date(from: day.components) {
                    dayAccessibilityText = self?.dayDateFormatter.string(from: date)
                } else {
                    dayAccessibilityText = nil
                }
                
                return CalendarItemModel<DayView>(
                    invariantViewProperties: .init(textColor: textColor, isSelectedStyle: self?.containsBookDate(day: day) ?? false),
                    viewModel: .init(dayText: "\(day.day)", dayAccessibilityText: dayAccessibilityText))
                
            }
    }
```

The strange is that the month string of calendar view is "2020 M01", "2020 M02", ...
I expected to get "2020 January", ...
The above code is just for customizing day view and for month is use the formatted is provided the library as-is.

```
let monthHeaderDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    monthHeaderDateFormatter.calendar = calendar
    monthHeaderDateFormatter.locale = calendar.locale
    monthHeaderDateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(
      fromTemplate: "MMMM yyyy",
      options: 0,
      locale: calendar.locale ?? Locale.current)
```

It's the library's default code for month format.
I've compared my code and libraries' example but not found the difference and tested on the example on my iPhone, it shows the expected result.
Of course, I might make a mistake but it would be helpful to know when such an issue happens.
Any help will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: is your date format is "MMMM yyyy" why do you use a library to get the dateFormat use just plain string instead monthHeaderDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"

Comment: It's the library's (cocoa pod) code. 
The sample app works well. Seems the library doesn't have a problem.
What I'd like to know is what is "2020 M01" and when such an issue happens

Answer (score 0):

Just had the exactly same issue. You probably need to change how you create input `Calendar` for the lib to use (this code):

```swift
private lazy var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
```

I can't say exactly when it started, but newly created calendars now have `"fixed"` locale instead of current one. And dates are formatted wrongly, for this strange locale. So, if you assign proper locale manually, it just works:

```swift
private lazy var calendar: Calendar = {
    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.locale = .current // or whatever locale you need
    return calendar
}
```